# Looping the allow message when try connect Unreal EOS

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-engine5, dedicated-server, eos

I am using the EOSCore plugin to create a Dedicated server, I had success to create the server, but when I try to connect a client it opens the overlay to login on my account and I make the login appears another screen to me allow the connect with my account with the application, when I click in allow connection the screen is hidden and some seconds after it backs the screen of Allow the app connection and never connects, I tryed in the editor, as stand alone, and with a packad project. After that I tryed use directly the C++ approuch without the plugin, and have the same result. The message of allows app to connect in an etternal loop. Someone can help me with it? I have here a video showing this.

https://youtu.be/37abS1K_ozk

Sorry for the english, I am not a native english speaker!